# asp.net connection issues

Tags: asp.net

This is my ASP.NET code:

```
<html>
<body>

<%
Dim Conn
Conn = "Provider=xxxxxx; Server=xxxxxx; Database=xxxxxx; Trusted_Connection=xxx; "


sql="INSERT INTO xxxx"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("xxxx") & "')"

on error resume next
Conn.Execute sql,recaffected
if err<>0 then
  Response.Write("Update Failed")
else
  Response.Write("<h3>"Record Added</h3>")
end if

%>

</body>
</html>
```

I always get a result of "Update Failed"... Can you see from the code why this is?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest a **major refactoring** to eliminate your SQL injection vulnerability.

```
Dim  conn As New SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString)
Dim  cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()

conn.Open()
cmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO MyTable(Column1, Column2)  " & _
                     " VALUES (@Value1, @Value2)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", Request.Form("xxxx"))
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", Request.Form("xxxx"))
'add all your parameters as per above  '

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the command text and use procedures, otherwise you open yourself to security holes.  NEVER put your SQL commands on your UI or code-behind.  Best practices is stored procedures.